# How to delete the root of a tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a binary tree.How can we delete the Top of the tree(the root)?I have a function called treeTop which returns the top of the tree,but how to delete it?
thats my tree:

```
data Tree a = Empty
| Leaf a
| Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) String
deriving (Show)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "deleting the top of the tree"? Remember that in Haskell the data structures are immutable so you will actually be returning a brand new tree instead of destructively modifying the old one.

Comment: By deleting the top i mean this:for example this is a tree(Node 5 (Node 7 (Leaf 9) (Leaf 10)) (Leaf 15) ) We have to delete 5 and replace it with the left or the right subtree.

Comment: So, you don't mean "delete the root" at all; you mean "how do I return a subtree"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is not a balanced tree, then

```
 deleteRoot :: Tree -> Maybe Tree
 deleteRoot (Node _ l r _) = Just $ append l r
 deleteRoot _            = Nothing
```

where `append` takes on tree, and sticks it on the end of another, implementing this is fairly mechanical

```
 append :: Tree -> Tree -> Tree
 append Empty r    = r
 append (Leaf a) r = <???>
 append (Node v l r s) r' = Node v l (append r r') s
```

Now the problem here is that when you're attempting to append `Leaf x` to `r`, it's not clear what to do. With `Empty` we just throw the value away since it has no useful information, but a `Leaf` does. You could promote the `Leaf` to a node with `Node a Empty r ""` for example, but there isn't a clear value to put in as that `String`. I'll leave it for you to decide.

This is obviously nonsense when the tree is supposed to be balanced, but if it's not, then we'll turn

```
             foo
            /    \
        bar        baz
       /   \      /   \
      0     0     0    0
```

Into

```
    bar
   /   \
  0    baz
      /   \
     0     0
```

Where `0` means `Empty`. Note that the original tree is unmodified, so if we fired up GHCi

```
 Main*> let test = Node () (Node () Empty Empty "bar") (Node () Empty Empty "baz") "foo"
 Main*> deleteRoot test
   Node Empty (Node Empty Empty "baz") "bar"
 Main*> test
   Node (Node () Empty Empty "bar") (Node () Empty Empty "baz") "foo"
```

So it doesn't modify the old text, but this is how things work in functional languages, rather than destroying old data, we keep it and create new immutable values.

My final code ends up as

```
data Tree a = Empty
            | Leaf a
            | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) String
            deriving (Show)

deleteRoot :: Tree a -> Maybe (Tree a)
deleteRoot (Node _ l r _) = Just $ append l r
deleteRoot _            = Nothing

append :: Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
append Empty r = r
append (Leaf a) r  = Node a Empty r ""
append (Node v l r s) r' = Node v l (append r r') s
```

Comment: It seems perfect.Thank you,but it shows me an Error on line deleteRoot Empty = Nothing .The error is "parse error on imput '='.

Comment: I've updated to fix some errors, but I didn't get that parse error, check ot make sure you've indented correctly :) @user3050163 you have an identation error in your example, You have to indent the constructors to be inline with `Empty`.

Comment: @user3050163 I've updated with my final code, take a look at that

Comment: Still gives me a parse error this time on imput _ in line deleteRoot (Node _ l r _) = Just $ append l r

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this error, how are you running this?

Comment: Ok,your code is correct,the problem is in me,but i still can't understand why it gives me this error.